# python3.5 startswith("#"):

Tags: list, append, startswith, python-3.5

In python3.5, how can I generate a list that contains the data, but does not contain any comments?

I've tried using:

```
list1=[]
if not startswith("#"):
    list1.append(data)
```

but data is also a list. There's clearly a disconnect.

Comment: Can you include the rest of your code?  I'm assuming there's a `for` loop surrounding that snippet.  Are you reading from a file?

Comment: Do you mean to write something like:

Comment: `data = ["dsdsds", "#fdfsfsdfs", "something", "#nothing"]

    list1 = []
    for text in data:
        if not text.startswith("#"):
            list1.append(text)
`